# How to get the three sticks of dynamite in West of Loathing?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I've gotten the first stick by learning Dickerin' through the book mom gives, then the second through trading a needle. How the heck do I get a third?

Comment: On my first playthrough i lost the bandit fight and the game felt sorry for me and gave me a dynamite, but i haven't been able to replicate it

Answer (score 5):

In the Thousand Snake Gulch, the location where you rescue the crazy horse, you fight three snakes. Lose to the third snake for the third stick of dynamite.
The easiest way to lose to the third snake is to unequip any equipment you're using.

After using 3 dynamite to access the box, you'll need to use a needle to unlock it. This means that you must grab the needle from the haystack at your house in order to get the reward, as you'll trade one needle for a stick of dynamite, use one needle to get the crowbar from the toolbox, and then this final needle on the reward.

The reward may disappoint you:
[image: screenshot of the reward, one meat]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where is the third snake? What is the reward?