# How do I get the third stick of dynamite?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I'm trying to blast open the crack in the wall in the orehole mine in boring springs, but I can't find all 3 dynamite. I got 2 from the trader, but can't find the last one. Where do I get it?

Comment: Although no answer yet, this question was asked already [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315957/how-to-get-the-three-sticks-of-dynamite-in-west-of-loathing?rq=1).

Comment: @TimmyJim I haven't played this game but if you read both questions it sounds like these users are missing a stick of dynamite the other has...

Comment: @BlueBarren having played the game, both askers have found the same 2 sticks of dynamite

Comment: @BlueBarren then it looks like I've accidentally answered the question?

Comment: @TimmyJim if that were true then I'd say yes but GodEmperorDune indicates the opposite.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer" :(

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'll test it and grab some screenshots at home to improve that answer, but in the meantime upvote, close vote, reverse vote

Answer (score 0):

Lose a fight with the third snake in the Snake Valley place, if that doesn't work, lose a fight with all enemies (excluding Soapy).